# TaskInternal.execute Migration

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

In a spring boot application in the build.gradle

```
task loadDbConfigFromSpringProfile {

  def activeProfileProperties = new Properties()
    file("src/main/resources/application.properties").withInputStream {
      activeProfileProperties.load(it)
    }

  def profileProperties = new Properties()
    file("src/main/resources/application-" + activeProfileProperties.getProperty("spring.profiles.active") + ".properties").withInputStream {
     profileProperties.load(it)
  }

  active_db_url = profileProperties.getProperty("spring.datasource.url")

}


loadDbConfigFromSpringProfile.execute()
```

When i run application with **gradle 4.4**, I get

> The TaskInternal.execute() method has been deprecated and is scheduled
>   to be removed in Gradle 5.0.

I started to create a class who extends  extends DefaultTask but I'm not sure if it's the easier way to fix issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the call to `loadDbConfigFromSpringProfile.execute()`, your code will have the same effect.

You do not even need the task definition, putting the following in your build file has the same effect:

```
def activeProfileProperties = new Properties()
file("src/main/resources/application.properties").withInputStream {
  activeProfileProperties.load(it)
}

def profileProperties = new Properties()
file("src/main/resources/application-" + activeProfileProperties.getProperty("spring.profiles.active") + ".properties").withInputStream {
   profileProperties.load(it)
}

active_db_url = profileProperties.getProperty("spring.datasource.url")
```

Here is why: The task you are defining has no actions. Actions can be added to a task by using `doLast` or `doFirst` as shown in the [hello world example](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:hello_world).

That also means that everything which is in the body of your task is executed at configuration time - since it is supposed to be configuring the task.

Therefore, `loadDbConfigFromSpringProfile.execute()` has no effect - the task is skipped since it has no actions.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace by `finalizedBy()`

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-call-task-execution-from-outside-task/25971